# How to install ZhuSuan a library for bayesian deep learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, installation

I want to install ZhuSuan a library for bayesian deep learning.The documentation says that:

> ZhuSuan is still under development. Before the first stable release (1.0), please clone the GitHub repository and run:
>
> ```
> pip install .
> ```

So I copied the link and run:

```
pip install https://github.com/thu-ml/zhusuan.git
```

However, I can't install it and during downloading I get an error:

> can't unpack the file

Comment: Open an issue in their repository.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a GitHub repository as a pip package, it will not work. You must `clone the GitHub repository` first (using SourceTree or any other tool).

Once you have cloned it (that means you downloaded it to your computer, using `Git`), go to that directory in your computer and run `pip install .` from that directory.

Comment: oh, Thanks a lot for your help. Could you please explain a bit more about clone and how do that?

Comment: simply google for `how to clone a repository from github` and you'll find plenty step-by-step instructions

Comment: feel free to `accept` my answer if it solved your problem

Comment: I was talking about clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/567244